# Directory Naming conventions on Javascript

Tags: javascript, package

I'm currently dividing a Javascript project into folders and I'm having a bad time coming up with names for the "packages". As of now I have the following code structure

```
project_name
|-- src
    |-- main
        |-- config
        |-- security
        |-- file-management
        |-- project_name.js // My "main" JS file
    |-- test
|-- envs
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
```

Is there a better way to modularize a JS project?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thanks, I ended up using the medium.com proposed naming convention. I did search on google before posting here, I wanted to know if there are other naming conventions or if there is a prefered one

Comment: This is mostly personal (team) choice, and mostly comes down to staying consistent. I personally use lower case package names without dashes or underscores (similar to java convention). But for some projects with multi-word package names (e.g. youtubeextractidsapi), it can be easier to read with camelcase package names (youtubeExtractIdsApi).